# How do I turn a 2.7 GB gct file into a dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I have a file that holds 2.7gb of raw data
I'm trying to normalize it using python pandas, making a workable dataframe from it

I cannot seem to handle the file size, I have tried reading the file in chunks, or subsetting before anything else so the file will be smaller. I even tried changing the dtype into something other than object but it didn't work.

Is there proper mannee or a methodology  to handle such a large file by python?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: What's a gct file?

Comment: Try [dask](https://dask.org/) for huge files.